# most lightweight ViewGroup for containers

Tags: android, android-layout

what is the ViewGroup you should use when needing a container e.g. for a fragmenttransaction? I am kind of between FrameLayout and LinearLayout from my feeling but I would like to make a decision on facts ;-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The android project template uses `FrameLayout` for fragment transactions, so I'd go with the `FrameLayout`